# reverse digits of an integer -- similar code different outputs

Tags: integer, reverse

for input 1534236469 I am getting 2 different answers in reverse and reverse1-- what is it reverse1 is doing that is wrong?

/**
 * Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer.
 * 
 * Example 1:
 * 
 * Input: 123 Output: 321 Example 2:
 * 
 * Input: -123 Output: -321 Example 3:
 * 
 * Input: 120 Output: 21 Note: Assume we are dealing with an environment which
 * could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−231, 231
 * − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0
 * when the reversed integer overflows.
 */

public class ReverseInteger {

```
public static int reverse1(int x) {
    int multiplicationFactor = 1;

    if (x < 0) {
        multiplicationFactor = -1;
    }
    x = Math.abs(x);
    int reverse = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        remainder = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;

    }

    if (reverse > Integer.MAX_VALUE || reverse < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }

    return reverse * multiplicationFactor;

}

public static int reverse(int x) {
    long reverse = 0;
    boolean negative = x < 0;
    x = Math.abs(x);
    while (x > 0) {
        int y = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + y;

    }
    if (negative) {
        reverse = -1 * reverse;
    }
    if (reverse > Integer.MAX_VALUE || reverse < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) reverse;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    reverse(1534236469);//output- 0
    reverse1(1534236469);//output- 1056389759
    // 2147483647

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

reverse1-- uses int reverse--there is an overflow of result--
reverse2 -- uses Long reverse--there is no overflow of result